# ngb-accordion apply scrolling/focus when activeIds is set

Tags: angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

i have many accordions on my site, each is displayed with ngb-accordion component in a `*ngFor` loop.

each accordion has a element identifier: `id="elem-{{row.id}}"`.
to open a specific panel, i use `activeIds`, that works great. but i wan't also to scroll to this element when it's open by default.

i've tried it in my component with:
`this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#elem-' + this.activeId).scrollIntoView();`

and tried it with .focus() on the above, but nothing works.

here my component-template:

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="plan-{{activeId}}">
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let planRow of plan$ | async" title="Spieltag {{planRow.gameday}}" id="plan-{{planRow.gameday}}">
  <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    <app-plan-row class="planRow" *ngFor="let row of planRow.rows" [row]="row"></app-plan-row>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```

and my component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): {
    this.plan$.subscribe(plan => {
        plan.forEach(planRow => {
            const dateBegin = moment(planRow.dateFrom);
            const dateEnds  = moment(planRow.dateTo);
            if (moment().isBetween(dateBegin, dateEnds)) {
                this.activeId = planRow.gameday;
                this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#plan-' + planRow.gameday).scrollIntoView();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: resolved this with using `ngAfterViewChecked`